# BindingSource.ResetBindings not working unless "true" passed

Tags: c#, data-binding, .net-4.0

I have a grid bound to a `BindingSource` (which is in turn bound to a `List<T>`).  When I change the underlying `List<T>` data and then call:

```
bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

the grid does **not** get updated.  But if I call:

```
bs.ResetBindings(true);
```

it **does** get updated.  My code is now working but I'm still puzzled why this is necessary.  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings.aspx) the parameter to `ResetBindings` should be set to:

> **true** if the data schema has changed; **false** if only values have changed

I certainly did not change any data schema... so why do I need **true** ?

Comment: What grid are you using? My guess is there may be a bug in how it handles ListChangedType.Reset notification.

Comment: I'm using DevExpress's XtraGrid

Comment: Is it possible you can use a decompiler such as ILSpy on the DevExpress code to see if it's a bug on their code? Also, is it possible you can try using a BindingList<T> instead of a passing a List<T> to a BindingSource and see if that will work.

Comment: I use DevExpress with good results. I suggest you to provide the binding source for grid control but also for grid view. If it is necessary, provide the data model to the binding source programaticaly. Do not use implicit view, just create your custom view. If nothing works as expected, search for help on the official site.

Comment: @JoelFan I have the same problem. I have a refresh button that calls bs.ResetBindings(false); When I change a value in the SQL Server Db table and click on refresh button the changed value does not display in either case using 'false' or 'true'. But if I reload the form the new value is displayed. I am using the DataGridView from .NET (not from Devexpress). It's working for [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13231743/1232087).

Answer (score 0):

If you have two types: Cat and Dog that both derive from Animal. This will not work properly:

from Designer.cs

```
animalBindingSource1.DataSource = typeof(Animal);
```

and then in in e.g Form_Load

```
List<Cat> cats = getCats();
animalBindingSource1.DataSource = cats;
```

Try using a BindingList, e.g.

```
animalBindingSource1.DataSource = new BindingList<Animal>(cats);
```

Post your code if it doesn't work. There's probably nothing wrong with the devexpress gridcontrol.

Comment: Rereading your post: are you using DataSets for the DataSource?

Comment: is it necessary to first assign it a Type and then an actual instance?

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
bs.DataSource = ListOfMyObjectOrWhatEver; //EVEN IF ALREADY MADE!
bs.ResetBindings(false);
grid.Refresh();
```

Hope it helps...