# Unable to UPDATE DataGrid with ComboBox values in C# using SQL Update Query

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to make a change to the Data-Grid values by using an "UPDATE query" but for some reason I am unable to update the Combo-Box.

The updating of the other fields works fine and I am not getting an error.

I am using 3-Tier Architecture with Stored Procedures so the Data flows from my Database through 2 classes until it reaches my Form class to Present to the User.

Here is my UPDATE Query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[us_ChangeProject] 

@ProjectID varchar(10),
@ProjectTitle varchar(50),
@ProjectDescription nvarchar(50),
@ProjectStartDate smalldatetime,
@ProjectDueDate smalldatetime,
@ProjectOwner nvarchar(10),
@SupervisorID varchar(10),
@ProjectStatus nvarchar(10)

 UPDATE  ProjectTable
 SET  ProjectTitle = @ProjectTitle, ProjectDescription = 
 @ProjectDescription,ProjectStartDate = @ProjectStartDate, 
 ProjectDueDate = @ProjectDueDate,ProjectOwner = @ProjectOwner, 
 SupervisorID = @SupervisorID, ProjectStatus = @ProjectStatus 
 WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectID
```

The Data-Access Layer method that calls the Stored Procedures:

```
public DataTable GetAllProjects()
    {
        DataTable dtProjects = new DataTable();
        string sqlinsert = "SELECT * FROM ProjectTable";

        using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZEUS\\MSSQLSERVERDEV;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (var dbCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlinsert, dbConn))
            {
                using (var dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCmd))
                {
                    dbAdapter.Fill(dtProjects);

                    return dtProjects;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public DataTable GetAllStudentNames()
    {
        DataTable dtStudents = new DataTable();
        string sqlinsert = "us_GetAllStudentNames";

        using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZEUS\\MSSQLSERVERDEV;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (var dbCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlinsert, dbConn))
            {
                using (var dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCmd))
                {                        
                    dbAdapter.Fill(dtStudents);

                    return dtStudents;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public DataTable GetAllSupervisorNames()
    {
        DataTable dtSupervisors = new DataTable();
        string sqlinsert = "us_GetAllSupervisorNames";

        using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZEUS\\MSSQLSERVERDEV;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (var dbCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlinsert, dbConn))
            {
                using (var dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCmd))
                {                        
                    dbAdapter.Fill(dtSupervisors);

                    return dtSupervisors;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public int InsertProject(string projectID, string projectTitle, string projectDescription, string projectStartDate, string projectDueDate, string projectOwner, string projectSupervisor, string projectStatus)
     {        

        string sqlinsert = "us_InsertProject";

        using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZEUS\\MSSQLSERVERDEV;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (var dbCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlinsert, dbConn))
            {

                dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = projectID;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = projectTitle;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectDescription", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = projectDescription;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectStartDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = projectStartDate;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectDueDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = projectDueDate;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwner", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = projectOwner;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@SupervisorID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = projectSupervisor;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = projectStatus;

                dbConn.Open();

                int x = dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return x;
            }
        }

    }

public int ChangeProject(string projectID, string projectTitle, string projectDescription, string projectStartDate, string projectDueDate, string projectOwner, string projectSupervisor, string projectStatus)
    {
        string sqlinsert = "us_ChangeProject";

        using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZEUS\\MSSQLSERVERDEV;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (var dbCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlinsert, dbConn))
            {

                dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = projectID;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = projectTitle;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectDescription", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = projectDescription;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectStartDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = projectStartDate;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectDueDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = projectDueDate;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwner", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = projectOwner;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@SupervisorID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = projectSupervisor;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = projectStatus;

                dbConn.Open();

                int x = dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return x;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then the Business Class':

```
class Projects
{
    DataAccessLayer dl = new DataAccessLayer();

    public string ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProjectStartDate { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDueDate { get; set; }
    public string ProjectOwner { get; set; }
    public string ProjectSupervisor { get; set; }
    public string ProjectStatus { get; set; }

 public DataTable GetAllProjects()
    {
        return dl.GetAllProjects();
    }

    public int InsertProject(string projectID, string projectTitle, string projectDescription, string projectStartDate, string projectDueDate, string projectOwner, string projectSupervisor, string projectStatus)
    {
        return dl.InsertProject(projectID, projectTitle, projectDescription, projectStartDate, projectDueDate, projectOwner, projectSupervisor, projectStatus);
    }

public int ChangeProject(string projectID, string projectTitle, string projectDescription, string projectStartDate, string projectDueDate, string projectOwner, string projectSupervisor, string projectStatus)
    {
        return dl.ChangeProject(projectID, projectTitle, projectDescription, projectStartDate, projectDueDate, projectOwner, projectSupervisor, projectStatus);
    }

}

class Student
{
    DataAccessLayer dl = new DataAccessLayer();
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentFirstName { get; set; }
    public string StudentSurname { get; set; }
    public string StudentCellNo { get; set; }
    public string StudentStatus { get; set; }

    public DataTable GetAllStudentNames()
    {
        return dl.GetAllStudentNames();
    }

    public DataTable GetAllStudents()
    {
        return dl.GetAllStudents();
    }

    public int InsertStudent(string StudentID, string StudentFirstName, string StudentSurname, string StudentCellNo, string StudentStatus)
    {
        return dl.InsertStudent(StudentID, StudentFirstName, StudentSurname, StudentCellNo, StudentStatus);
    }
}

class Supervisor
{
    DataAccessLayer dl = new DataAccessLayer();
    public string SupervisorID { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorFirstName { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorSurname { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorCellNo { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorStatus { get; set; }

    public DataTable GetAllSupervisorNames()
    {
        return dl.GetAllSupervisorNames();
    }

    public DataTable GetAllSupervisors()
    {
        return dl.GetAllSupervisors();
    }

    public int InsertSupervisor(string SupervisorID, string SupervisorFirstName, string SupervisorSurname, string SupervisorCellNo, string SupervisorStatus)
    {
        return dl.InsertSupervisor(SupervisorID, SupervisorFirstName, SupervisorSurname, SupervisorCellNo, SupervisorStatus);
    }
}
```

And finally the Presentation Layer:

```
 public partial class frmProjects : Form
{
    Projects pr = new Projects();
    Student st = new Student();
    Supervisor su = new Supervisor();


    public frmProjects()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void frmProjects_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        dgvProjects.DataSource = pr.GetAllProjects();
        cmbOwner.DataSource = st.GetAllStudentNames();
        cmbOwner.DisplayMember = "FullName";
        cmbOwner.ValueMember = "StudentID";
        cmbOwner.Text = "";
        cmbSupervisor.DataSource = su.GetAllSupervisorNames();
        cmbSupervisor.DisplayMember = "SVFullName";
        cmbSupervisor.ValueMember = "SupervisorID";
        cmbSupervisor.Text = "";
    }


    private void dgvProjects_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvProjects.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow r = this.dgvProjects.SelectedRows[0];

            txtProjectID.Text = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txtProjectTitle.Text = r.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtDescription.Text = r.Cells[2].Value.ToString(); ;
            dteStartDate.Text = r.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dteDueDate.Text = r.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            cmbOwner.Text = r.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            cmbSupervisor.Text = r.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            txtStatus.Text = r.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        }
    }


    private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pr.ChangeProject(txtProjectID.Text, txtProjectTitle.Text, txtDescription.Text, dteStartDate.Text, dteDueDate.Text, cmbOwner.SelectedValue.ToString(), cmbSupervisor.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtStatus.Text);

        dgvProjects.DataSource = pr.GetAllProjects();
    }
}
```

Here are the Stored Procedures that load with the Form filling the Data-Grid and the two Combo-Box's:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_GetAllProjects] 

SELECT ProjectID, ProjectTitle, ProjectDescription, ProjectStartDate, ProjectDueDate, StudentSurname + ' ' + StudentFirstName AS OwnerName, SupervisorSurname + ' ' + SupervisorFirstName AS SupervisorName, ProjectStatus   
FROM ProjectTable, SupervisorTable, StudentTable WHERE ProjectTable.SupervisorID = SupervisorTable.SupervisorID AND ProjectOwner = StudentID 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[us_GetAllSupervisorNames] 

SELECT SupervisorID, SupervisorFirstName + ' ' + SupervisorSurname AS SVFullName FROM SupervisorTable

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[us_GetAllStudentnames] 

SELECT StudentID, StudentSurname + ' ' + StudentFirstName AS FullName FROM StudentTable
```

Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: 1) Where is the combobox? 2) How do you fill the combobox? 3) What do you mean unable to update the combox?

Comment: @CodingYoshi The Combo Box's are 'cmbSupervisor' and 'cmbStudent' in C# and they get data from the Stored Procedures : '[dbo].[us_GetAllStudentnames]' & '[dbo].[us_GetAllSupervisorNames]'. The goal is to get information from the Data Grid by selecting a row in it which then fills the corresponding text box on the form. Then  i should be able to change that information and after clicking my event button it goes back to the grid with the new data thus updating the row. The column that has the combo box values is the only one that doesn't change when i want it to

Comment: @CodingYoshi sorry if the post is too vague. I am struggling to find the wording since there is no error to tell me what the problem is. Also i edited the code to include anything related to the Combo Box which should explain how it gets filled with data

Comment: Try to set the datasource of the gridview to a binding source as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231149/datagridview-not-updating-refreshing).

Comment: @CodingYoshi thanks,I implemented the Binding Source and that seemed to do the trick